# My app is rejected because of donation on webView

Tags: google-play-console

I have an app using webView for my blog. Inside of the blog, there is a donation button.

Google Play says

```
Apps that employ in-store or in-app purchases must comply with the following guidelines: 
In-store purchases:Developers charging for apps and downloads from Google Play must use Google Play’s payment system.
In-app purchases:
Developers offering products within a game downloaded on Google Play or providing access to game content must use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of payment.
Developers offering products within another category of app downloaded on Google Play must use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of payment, except for the following cases:
Payment is solely for physical products
Payment is for digital content that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g. songs that can be played on other music players).
In-app virtual currencies must only be used within the app or game title for which they were purchased.
Developers must not mislead users about the apps they are selling nor about any in-app services, goods, content, or functionality offered for purchase. If your product description on Google Play refers to in-app features that may require a specific or additional charge, your description must clearly notify users that payment is required to access those features.
```

But I am not selling things in theory. I just ask my reader "If you like my blog, buy a cup of coffee"

Is it strictly forbidden for donation in this case?

There is a really weird thing. I have exactly the same app of webView in another language.
My English app was rejected for using Youtube and the Donation button. Meanwhile, the app in another language with donation and youtube was granted without the problem.

I ticked on the box about 'there is a paid thing' when I applied for the app on Google Play Console. Still, it's rejected.. What should I do now? Is there any solution to keep using the donation on the website?

Comment: Does the button initialize a money transaction api? if yes, you may be able to work around it by putting a link to the donation page of your website and get the donations there.

Comment: @MehranB Thank you for your advice. Yes, I am using a plugin for Paypal donation.  I was thinking to delete the donation button to be accepted. Then once it is granted, I might put it back. But maybe for safety, I should follow your instruction. Thanks!

Comment: I don't recommend sneaking the button back in because your app is reviewed on every update you publish and also you have record of being warned about it. it may lead to losing your account.

Comment: @MehranB I didn't know they will stop my account for it. I thought maybe they just reject my app again if they find it again. It's really weird how come another same app in a different language was accepted with a donation button, but this English app is not accepted. Maybe it's not checked by bot, but human. Some workers accepted app easily, but workers in English are so strict maybe? It's the third time to be rejected. I will use just a link for donation now for the English app.  Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic